# Regex: Find those words that doesn't have html tags on line, and add tags before and after

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have these 3 lines. The words in the second line are missing html tags.

```
<p class="mb-40px">ARTICOL START</p>
ARTICOL START
<p class="mb-40px">ARTICOL START</p>
```

I need to make a regex that cand find the lines that doesn't have html tags, and add tags to it:

My regex is not very good, because the words doesn't have space before or after it

**FIND:** `^(ARTICOL START)\s+`

**REPLACE BY:** `<p class="mb-40px">\1\</p>`

Comment: So all the lines you want to find are just `ARTICOL START` preceded/followed by nothing in the same line? Just use `^(ARTICOL START)$` if so.

Comment: yes, those lines

Comment: thanks a lot @Destroy666

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(ARTICOL START)(?s)$`
- Replace with: `<p class="mb-40px">\1\</p>`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

@Destroy666 Alternative, you can use simple:

- Find what: `^(ARTICOL START)$`